# Kubernetes kubeflow scaling is not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

Kubernetes kubeflow scaling is not working

I have installed kubernetes, kubectl and ksonnet as per suggested.

I have created kubeflow namespace and deployed kubeflow core components.

Then, I have created ksonnet app and namespace and h2o3-scaling component.

Then, I have tried to run some examples. Everything is working fine.

I have followed all the stepes provided by this url https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-kubeflow

But horizontal scaling is not working as expected.

Thanks in advance. Please help anyone to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about H2O3, but Kubeflow itself doesn't really support autoscaling. There are few components:

1. Tf-operator - it doesn't run training itself, it runs pods that run training and you specify number of replicas in TFJob definition, so no autoscaling.
2. Tf-serving - potentially could do autoscaling, but we don't right now, again you specify replicas.
3. Jupyterhub - same as tf-operator, spawns pods, don't autoscale.

What is exact use case you're aiming for?